# Underscore js find item by ID

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm new to Underscore js and bit confused on how to use it. I have a collection of 'goals' and I want to find one of it by ID.

here's the data:

```
{"goal":[
    {
        "category" : "education",
        "title" : "Charlie University",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "date" : "01/03/2020",
        "value" : 50000,
        "achievability" : 3,
        "experimental_achievability": 3,
        "suggested": false,
        "accounts": [
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            }
        ],
        "articles": [
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            }
        ],
        "related_goals": [
            {
                ...
            }
        ],
        "id":"1"
    },
    {
        "category" : "family",
        "title" : "Getting married",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "date" : "01/03/2022",
        "value" : 10000,
        "achievability" : 3,
        "experimental_achievability": 2,
        "suggested": true,
        "accounts": [
            {
                ...
            }
        ],
        "articles": [
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            }
        ],
        "related_goals": [
            {
                ...
            }
        ],
        "id":"2"
    }
    ...
]}
```

That's what I'm trying, I want to get the entire array/object so I can get each field of it:

```
var goalId = 1;
_.each(result.goal, function(item){
    _.find(result.goal, function(i){
         return i = goalId;
    });
});
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: refer underscore js documentation,
url: http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere

Answer (score 99, accepted):

## Update

It's 2016 and we might not acutally need underscore to achieve that. Using `Array.prototype.find()`. It returns a value in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

```
  // Underscore
  var users = [
    { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
    { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
    { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
  ]

  _.find(users, function (o) { return o.age < 40; })
  // output: object for 'barney'

  // Native
  var users = [
    { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
    { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
    { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
  ]

  users.find(function (o) { return o.age < 40; })
  // output: object for 'barney'
```

Browser support

```
--------------------------------------------
| Chrome | Firefox | Safari |  IE  | Opera |
|--------|---------|--------|------|-------|
|   45   |    25   |  7.1   | Edge |  32   |
--------------------------------------------
```

More information an polyfill on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

---

**Update**: I found that `_.where` always returns an array. [`_.findWhere`](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) returns the first object it finds so it will be better to use if you expect a single object in return.

---

You can use [`_.where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where) It's much easier.

If it's something like this :

```
var goal  = [

    {
        "category" : "education",
        "title" : "Charlie University",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "date" : "01/03/2020",
        "value" : 50000,
        "achievability" : 3,
        "experimental_achievability": 3,
        "suggested": false,
        "accounts": [],
        "articles": [],
        "related_goals": [],
        "id":"1"
    },
    {
        "category" : "education",
        "title" : "Charlie University",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "date" : "01/03/2020",
        "value" : 50000,
        "achievability" : 3,
        "experimental_achievability": 3,
        "suggested": false,
        "accounts": [],
        "articles": [],
        "related_goals": [],
        "id":"2"
    },
    {
        "category" : "education",
        "title" : "Charlie University",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "date" : "01/03/2020",
        "value" : 50000,
        "achievability" : 3,
        "experimental_achievability": 3,
        "suggested": false,
        "accounts": [],
        "articles": [],
        "related_goals": [],
        "id":"3"
    },
    {
        "category" : "education",
        "title" : "Charlie University",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "date" : "01/03/2020",
        "value" : 50000,
        "achievability" : 3,
        "experimental_achievability": 3,
        "suggested": false,
        "accounts": [],
        "articles": [],
        "related_goals": [],
        "id":"4"
    }
]
```

You can use something like :

```
var filteredGoal = _.where(goal, {id: "1"});
```

Comment: yep - better than my solution!

Comment: Best thing about undersocre() is its documentation ... I head directly to the docs, search for what I need and if it's there I will find it.

Comment: so do i. bad habits i guess using the same functions all the time. but thanks for pointing out the usefulness of _.where() i will bear it in mind in future

Comment: The .findWhere was what I needed for a more concise solution.  Thank you.

Comment: Can underscore _.findWhere handle sub properties, like lodash _.find can? (https://lodash.com/docs#find) So that I can search for chr.age < 40 for example?

Answer (score 21):

You are using Array of objects. So,you can use: _.***findWhere***(Looks through the list and returns the first value that matches all of the key-value pairs ) to get the all the properties based on id or other key attribute.

```
var some= [
             {Employee:'ved',id:20}, 
             {Employee:"ved",age:25},
             {Employee:"p",age:2}
          ];

var a = _.findWhere(some,{id:20});
console.log('searchResult',a);
```

To get the index, you can use something like this:

```
var b = _.indexOf(some,a);
console.log('index',b);
```

***If you need all list of uses***,
**TRY**:  ***_.where***(It looks through each occurrence  in the array, returning an array of all the values that contain the key-value pairs listed in properties.)

```
var some= [ 
            {Employee:"ved",id:20}, 
            {Employee:"ved prakash",id:20},
            {Employee:"anyone",id:2}
          ];
var a = _.where(some,{id:25});
    console.log('searchResult',a);
```

> _.find: It is used to check the value only, not Key-value both.

Visit Docs:[_.find](http://underscorejs.org/#find)

Answer (score 15):

Have simplified your data model, but something like this?

```
var goals = [{id:1, name:'Goal1'},
             {id:2, name:'Goal2'},
             {id:3, name:'Goal3'}];

function getGoal(id) {
    return _.find(goals, function(goal) {
        return goal.id === id;
    });
}

alert(getGoal(2).name);
```

You can see this in action in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GugDD/).

Comment: I like this answer because the question is asking for a single item to be returned so _.find() seems more appropriate than _.where().  Typically when I pass in an ID I expect either one result or zero not a possible array of items.

Comment: Hey Gwyn, jsfiddle links are awesome, but it's generally a good idea to also include the code in the body of the post. If the jsfiddle link were to ever break, your answer would be useless to future visitors. Please consider an [edit] to include the code in the body as well to help ensure this helps others for years to come. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I added back in the jsFiddle link for you. That's still helpful and useful, but now folks can decide if they need more information and click the link if they do or simply consume what's on the page. In short, links are still cool, just not by themselves. :)